# AngularJS template

Tags: angularjs

**Hello Stack Over Flow community, i'm working on a big project using springboot framework and AngularJS, I am new to angularJS, i've just started learning it for not more than 4 days, i'm trying to use a AngularJS template in order to make my work easier, i choosed a template that contains most of functions that i need in my project, but the problem is that the structure and the syntaxes are so diffrent of what i've seen in angularJS and i don't know which version of angular it is, knowing that i don't have documentation of this template, here's an example of how the code of most of files looks like and the structure too, can you guys help me to know which angular version is?? Structure of the template[Structure of the template 2]`define(['layout/module', 'lodash', 'notification'], function (module, _) {

```
'use strict';

module.registerDirective('demoStates', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/layout/directives/demo/demo-states.tpl.html',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.parent().css({
                position: 'relative'
            });

            element.on('click', '#demo-setting', function () {
                element.toggleClass('activate')
            })
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            var $root = $('body');

            $scope.$watch('fixedHeader', function (fixedHeader) {
                localStorage.setItem('sm-fixed-header', fixedHeader);
                $root.toggleClass('fixed-header', fixedHeader);
                if (fixedHeader == false) {
                    $scope.fixedRibbon = false;
                    $scope.fixedNavigation = false;
                }
            });


            $scope.$watch('fixedNavigation', function (fixedNavigation) {
                localStorage.setItem('sm-fixed-navigation', fixedNavigation);
                $root.toggleClass('fixed-navigation', fixedNavigation);
                if (fixedNavigation) {
                    $scope.insideContainer = false;
                    $scope.fixedHeader = true;
                } else {
                    $scope.fixedRibbon = false;
                }
            });


            $scope.$watch('fixedRibbon', function (fixedRibbon) {
                localStorage.setItem('sm-fixed-ribbon', fixedRibbon);
                $root.toggleClass('fixed-ribbon', fixedRibbon);
                if (fixedRibbon) {
                    $scope.fixedHeader = true;
                    $scope.fixedNavigation = true;
                    $scope.insideContainer = false;
                }
            });

            $scope.$watch('fixedPageFooter', function (fixedPageFooter) {
                localStorage.setItem('sm-fixed-page-footer', fixedPageFooter);
                $root.toggleClass('fixed-page-footer', fixedPageFooter);
            });

            $scope.$watch('insideContainer', function (insideContainer) {
                localStorage.setItem('sm-inside-container', insideContainer);
                $root.toggleClass('container', insideContainer);
                if (insideContainer) {
                    $scope.fixedRibbon = false;
                    $scope.fixedNavigation = false;
                }
            });

            $scope.$watch('rtl', function (rtl) {
                localStorage.setItem('sm-rtl', rtl);
                $root.toggleClass('smart-rtl', rtl);
            });

            $scope.$watch('menuOnTop', function (menuOnTop) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('$smartLayoutMenuOnTop', menuOnTop);
                localStorage.setItem('sm-menu-on-top', menuOnTop);
                $root.toggleClass('menu-on-top', menuOnTop);

                if(menuOnTop)$root.removeClass('minified');
            });

            $scope.$watch('colorblindFriendly', function (colorblindFriendly) {
                localStorage.setItem('sm-colorblind-friendly', colorblindFriendly);
                $root.toggleClass('colorblind-friendly', colorblindFriendly);
            });


            $scope.fixedHeader = localStorage.getItem('sm-fixed-header') == 'true';
            $scope.fixedNavigation = localStorage.getItem('sm-fixed-navigation') == 'true';
            $scope.fixedRibbon = localStorage.getItem('sm-fixed-ribbon') == 'true';
            $scope.fixedPageFooter = localStorage.getItem('sm-fixed-page-footer') == 'true';
            $scope.insideContainer = localStorage.getItem('sm-inside-container') == 'true';
            $scope.rtl = localStorage.getItem('sm-rtl') == 'true';
            $scope.menuOnTop = localStorage.getItem('sm-menu-on-top') == 'true' || $root.hasClass('menu-on-top');
            $scope.colorblindFriendly = localStorage.getItem('sm-colorblind-friendly') == 'true';


            $scope.skins = appConfig.skins;

            $scope.smartSkin = localStorage.getItem('sm-skin') || appConfig.smartSkin;


            $scope.setSkin = function (skin) {
                $scope.smartSkin = skin.name;
                $root.removeClass(_.pluck($scope.skins, 'name').join(' '));
                $root.addClass(skin.name);
                localStorage.setItem('sm-skin', skin.name);
                $("#logo img").attr('src', skin.logo);
            };


            if($scope.smartSkin != "smart-style-0"){
                $scope.setSkin(_.find($scope.skins, {name: $scope.smartSkin}))
            }


            $scope.factoryReset = function () {
                $.SmartMessageBox({
                    title: "<i class='fa fa-refresh' style='color:green'></i> Clear Local Storage",
                    content: "Would you like to RESET all your saved widgets and clear LocalStorage?1",
                    buttons: '[No][Yes]'
                }, function (ButtonPressed) {
                    if (ButtonPressed == "Yes" && localStorage) {
                        localStorage.clear();
                        location.reload()
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

});
`**

Comment: Do you learn Angularjs with the version < 2 or Angular with the version >2 because this is a normal directive for AngularJS

Comment: check your package.json or the script tags in your main html ,how we can guess what version you use?

Comment: this is what i want to know, because it's not mentioned which version it is in the template support

Comment: i didn't find any package.json file in the template

Comment: This is 1.x.x with some custome JavaScript functions ($.SmartMessageBox, )